# Android install referrer : pcampaignid=APPU_2

Tags: android, google-play, install-referrer, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I'm using `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0` lib to track installation referrer, work fine,

but I'm getting a lot of `pcampaignid=APPU_2_.........`

What does this mean?

Comment: Did you find it out ?

Comment: interested in the answer either

Comment: I'm interested as well

Comment: Any answer from your side ?

Comment: What is the significance of appu_2. I usually get inline|youtubeads|94161XX

Answer (score 3):

Seems that it's related to a campaign, Just decompose key as **p** **campaign** **id**. However, After looking deeper into docs, I didn't find any official documentation that mentions this. It seems garbage value because it doesn't make any sense and not related to the referral. The library is officially developed by Google, We can only aspect a perfect answer from them. Well, there are so many communities in varieties of language over the internet, where this question has been asked but not with a single response at all. It is highly possible that it's a campaign id of google's itself with is linked to the library code/[this page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) where the library docs hosted. However, these are all assumptions missing the evidence.

Also, I suggest going through [Collecting the Mobile Device IDs list](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9441463?hl=en), Where the remarketing is done through the device id. here in case, google must be using analytics to identify device id and referrals. So the chances are higher for **pcampaignid=APPU_2_.........** as a google's internal campaign id.

> Note: If you search about this, You'll find the same question asked in all the different languages everywhere. This is the only satisfactory description so far.

Answer (score 1):

I found the unofficial information that "pcampaignid" is used as Campaign-ID for tracking from where the app link was opened. Sofar I understood it, it is possible to track from where the people open the link to install your app. For example if you have an advertisment flyers (download links as QR-code) for your app on paper or on other places like Busses or Taxi cars etc. Than you can use a diferent Campaign-IDs to track from where your app was downloaded.
Unfortunately I can not found the link where I found this explanation any more.